# Is it possbile to have a null value on Example table on Cucumber Scenario Outline?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Here is my example table on my scenario outline, some does not have value, is this possible?

```
Examples:

|ID   | UserName   | Password  | Contact1 | Number       |

|ID1  | username1  | password1 | Phone    | 111 222 4444 |

|ID2  | username2  | password2 |          |              |

|ID3  | username3  | password3 | Email    | a@a.com      |

|ID4  | username4  | password4 |          |              |
```

Comment: @JeffC the question that you marked as a duplicate of this is about empty strings, whereas this is about null, which is quite different. This page is Google's first result when querying "gherkin null data table".

Comment: @LennyT I didn't mark it as a dup (two years ago... btw). If I did, you would have seen an autocomment that said something like "Possible duplicate of xxxx". Some mod did thus the Community tag.

Comment: @Jeff Weird! It says "marked as duplicate by JeffC, Community" on my screen but I don't really understand the inner workings of SO.

Comment: @LennyT Agreed... it is kinda confusing. It says the same thing on my screen but I think when multiple people vote close, it chooses the most used vote reason and in this case probably chose the admin's choice (the dup). The way I can tell it wasn't me is that it would have put that autocomment with my name and since that isn't here, I know it wasn't me... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty value will be considered a String if the feature step looks something like this:

```
Given ...
When I enter my "<Username>" and "<Password>"
And I enter my "<Contact>"
And I enter my "<Number>"
Then ...
```

You can manage the empty string inside the step definition:

```
@When("^I enter my \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_enter_my(String contact) throws Throwable {
    // Handle empty string as null
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Just an exmple, not sure if the code will work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, my question really is on the Example Data table, I have fields that is not required but some records has value in it and some does not.. can I leave the Example table blank or null?

Comment: Like on my example Contact 1 and Number is not required fields so line 2 and 4 does not have values

Comment: Yes you can leave the example table with no values. Be sure to handle it inside the step definition.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I was to make this work by adding " " on the null  values