# How to pass null data to String field in cucumber feature file?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber

Feature: login

Scenario Outline: validate userid

```
Given launch gmail site
```

Then validate userid with "" criteria

```
When enter password as "<z>"

And click pwd button

Then validate password with "<b>" criteria

And close site

Examples: 
  | x            | y       | z            | b       |
  | a            | valid   | 888654554    | valid   |
  |  b           | valid   |              | invalid |
  |              | invalid |              |         |
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not pass null values. When you pass an empty value, it will be seen as an empty string.
You could however change an empty value to a null value in your step definition file.

Comment: how to make null value in step definition file

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081350/is-it-possbile-to-have-a-null-value-on-example-table-on-cucumber-scenario-outlin

Comment: i did what u said